# Kubernetes Init Container fail fast

Tags: kubernetes

I have an [Init Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that does a database version check. If the database version check in the Init Container fails, the whole Deployment should fail immediately. But I still want the other Containers in the Pod to `restartPolicy=Always`.

However, Init Containers are

> retried according to the Pod `restartPolicy`

It would be good if I could specify a different `restartPolicy` for the Init Container than the Deployment but that's not possible. [Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) wouldn't really work either as what you need for this use case is a `PreStart` hook.

Is there a good way to get Init Containers to fail fast?

Comment: The issue isn’t so much failing fast, it’s that it will keep checking and failing over and over. This is generally preferred as it leads to convergent behavior over time. Like if the db pod crashes and comes back, your pod will check again and come back too.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to spin a separate container, which will be checking db version and if succeeds, creates some artifact, like file `/tmp/db_version` on the host's drive and then you just add **livenessProbe/readinessProbe** to your main Deployment, which will be checking existence of the `/tmp/db_version`, e.g.

```
livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - ls
        - /tmp/db_version
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Thus you'll be able to sideline **restartPolicy** of the db_version_check container and your main container.